# Weight bearing capacity of a terrace with a 10" concrete floor reinforced with steel bars?

Tags: structural-engineering

I want to put a stone table on a first floor terrace, approx weight of table top is 175kgs, and the base would be about 100kgs.  Table dimensions if relevant is 42inches diameter.  The base of the terrace is 10inch concrete with steel reinforcing bars.
Is there any danger this will overload the floor of the terrace?

Comment: How good was the concrete mixed?

Comment: `Is there any danger` cannot be answered `no`

Comment: First floor in the American or British convention?